# How can I express $3 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdots (4n+3)$ in terms of factorial?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, products, infinite-product

This is the work I have done so far:

$\prod_{k=0}^n(4k+3) = \frac{(4n)!}{2^n(2n)!}\cdot\prod_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{4k+1}$.

I would really appreciate a clever trick how to reduce the latter product that involves $\frac{1}{4k+1}$ ;)

Comment: Check out [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: Do you have any dumbed-down explanation for a miserable undergraduate student? :( I got the motivation part but can barely understand the latter parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are Quadruple factorial numbers, see [OEIS A008545](https://oeis.org/A008545) for the formula. The sequence starts with
$$
1, 3, 21, 231, 3465, 65835, 1514205, 40883535, 1267389585, 
$$

$$
44358635475, 1729986783525, \cdots
$$

Comment: Thank you. I can now spend some time investigating the function.